# Spring starter with @Service and autowired dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have module A. This module A has a service

```
@Service
public class MyService{
   @Autowired
   private CustomDependency dependency

   @Autowired
   private AnotherDependency anotherDependency

   ....
}
```

As you can see this service has dependencies autowired from included maven dependencies.

Now, what i want to create is custom **spring-starter**. But how do i create it if i am using @Service and it has autowired dependencies?

can i do something like:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(Greeter.class)
@ComponentScan(path to myservice class )
public class MyServiceConfiguration{}
```

Or how do i let the configuration know to pick up @Service

Is the only way to do

```
@Bean
public MyService myService(){
    CustomDependency customDependency = // get this bean from spring context
    AnotherDependency anotherDependency = // get this bean from spring context

    return new MyService(dependency,anotherDependency);
}
```

Or is there actually a way how to use @Service ?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is a good practice to do the injection by the constructor and not the properties.

You can achieve what you want by creating the bean manually. Spring Boot will provide the two dependencies beans when creating yours.

For example:

```java
public class MyService{
   private CustomDependency dependency;
   private AnotherDependency anotherDependency;

   public MyService (CustomDependency dependency, AnotherDependency anotherDependency) {
       this.dependency = dependency;
       this.anotherDependency = anotherDependency;
   }

   ....
}
```

Configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(Greeter.class)
public class MyServiceConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public MyService myService(CustomDependency dependency, AnotherDependency anotherDependency){
        return new MyService(dependency,anotherDependency);
    }
}
```